# pthread_create without separate function

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have an array of `pthread_t`s which are started within a for-loop via `pthread_create`.

I have a ton of variables that are declared beforehand and are important for the inner workings of the thread. I would like to have an anonymous inner function as start-routine of the `pthread_create` like so:

```
pthread_create(threads[i], NULL, 

     { inner function here }

, NULL);
```

I know that C++ doesn't have this in particular so I thought maybe lambdas could be of help or maybe someone has another idea so that I do not have to create a seperate method and hand over all those variables that come before `pthread_create`.

Comment: Why not use `std::thread` instead? The standard threads support lambdas, IIRC. Since you mention lambdas, you probably have `std::thread` too.

Comment: I suggest you do some more research about [*lambda expressions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), a non-capturing lambda can be used as a function pointer. And read about [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use `std::thread`. Is it possible with pthreads?

Comment: Can you elaborate why `std::thread` would not be usable/possible while lambdas are?

Comment: If you have access to lambdas, you should have access to `std::thread` as well. They both came with the C++11 standard. Can you please elaborate on *why* you "cannot use `std::thread`"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a lambda expression does not capture anything, [the lambda object can be converted to a C function pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#ClosureType::operator_ret.28.2A.29.28params.29.28.29), so something like this will work:

```
pthread_t thr;
pthread_create (&thr, NULL,
                [] (void *closure) -> void * {
                  return nullptr;
                }, NULL);
```

The explicit return type of `void *` is needed because the inferred one usually will not be correct. Since you cannot use captures, you need to use the `closure` parameter to pass along a pointer to an object (and use `static_cast` to cast it to the correct type in the lambda), and for life-time reasons, it is probably necessary to allocate that on the heap.

(Also note that `pthreads[i]` as the first element to `pthread_create` does not look right, it's a pointer used to return part of the result, the ID of the new thread.)